# While deploying an efs stack i get the following error

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I get the following errors as shown in the picture attached.

The Kms key is not being created. What could most probably be done to resolve this issue. At what line could the changes be made.

[Error while deploying an efs stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZNIM.jpg)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Simple 3 tier web application template
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  InstanceType:
    Default: t2.micro
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  VpcBlock:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/16
    Description: >-
      The CIDR range for the VPC. This should be a valid private (RFC 1918) CIDR
      range.
  PublicSubnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 01 within the VPC
  PublicSubnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.64.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 02 within the VPC
  PrivateSubnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.128.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 01 within the VPC
  PrivateSubnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.192.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 02 within the VPC
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: Worker Network Configuration
        Parameters:
          - VpcBlock
          - PublicSubnet01Block
          - PublicSubnet02Block
          - PrivateSubnet01Block
          - PrivateSubnet02Block
Mappings:
  AWSInstanceType2Arch:
    t1.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.nano:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.10xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c1.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    c1.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    g2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVMG2
    g2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVMG2
    r3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hi1.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hs1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cr1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cc2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
  AWSRegionArch2AMI:
    us-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
      HVMG2: ami-0a584ac55a7631c0c
    us-west-2:
      HVM64: ami-a0cfeed8
      HVMG2: ami-0e09505bc235aa82d
    us-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-0bdb828fd58c52235
      HVMG2: ami-066ee5fd4a9ef77f1
    eu-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-047bb4163c506cd98
      HVMG2: ami-0a7c483d527806435
    eu-west-2:
      HVM64: ami-f976839e
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    eu-west-3:
      HVM64: ami-0ebc281c20e89ba4b
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    eu-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-0233214e13e500f77
      HVMG2: ami-06223d46a6d0661c7
    ap-northeast-1:
      HVM64: ami-06cd52961ce9f0d85
      HVMG2: ami-053cdd503598e4a9d
    ap-northeast-2:
      HVM64: ami-0a10b2721688ce9d2
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ap-northeast-3:
      HVM64: ami-0d98120a9fb693f07
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ap-southeast-1:
      HVM64: ami-08569b978cc4dfa10
      HVMG2: ami-0be9df32ae9f92309
    ap-southeast-2:
      HVM64: ami-09b42976632b27e9b
      HVMG2: ami-0a9ce9fecc3d1daf8
    ap-south-1:
      HVM64: ami-0912f71e06545ad88
      HVMG2: ami-097b15e89dbdcfcf4
    us-east-2:
      HVM64: ami-0b59bfac6be064b78
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ca-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-0b18956f
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    sa-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-07b14488da8ea02a0
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    cn-north-1:
      HVM64: ami-0a4eaf6c4454eda75
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    cn-northwest-1:
      HVM64: ami-6b6a7d09
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcBlock
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-VPC'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnets
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
  PrivateRouteTable01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet AZ1
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private01
  PrivateRouteTable02:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet AZ2
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private02
  PublicRoute:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  PrivateRoute01:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
      - NatGateway01
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable01
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway01
  PrivateRoute02:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
      - NatGateway02
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable02
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway02
  NatGateway01:
    DependsOn:
      - NatGatewayEIP1
      - PublicSubnet01
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayEIP1.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-NatGatewayAZ1'
  NatGateway02:
    DependsOn:
      - NatGatewayEIP2
      - PublicSubnet02
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayEIP2.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-NatGatewayAZ2'
  NatGatewayEIP1:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  NatGatewayEIP2:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  PublicSubnet01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 01
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '0'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet01'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
          Value: 1
  PublicSubnet02:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 02
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '1'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet02'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
          Value: 1
  PrivateSubnet01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 03
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '0'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet01'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
          Value: 1
  PrivateSubnet02:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Private Subnet 02
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '1'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet02'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
          Value: 1
  PublicSubnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PrivateSubnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable01
  PrivateSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable02
  ControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Cluster communication with worker nodes
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet01
        - !Ref PublicSubnet02
      CrossZone: 'true'
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
      HealthCheck:
        Target: 'HTTP:80/'
        HealthyThreshold: '3'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
        Interval: '30'
        Timeout: '5'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref ELBWebServerSecurityGroup
  ELBWebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  AsgLaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-launch-template'
      LaunchTemplateData:
        CreditSpecification:
          CpuCredits: Unlimited
        ImageId:
          'Fn::FindInMap':
            - AWSRegionArch2AMI
            - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
            - 'Fn::FindInMap':
                - AWSInstanceType2Arch
                - Ref: InstanceType
                - Arch
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        Monitoring:
          Enabled: true
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref ELBWebServerSecurityGroup
        UserData:
          'Fn::Base64': >
            #!/bin/bash

            yum update -y

            yum install httpd -y

            service httpd start

            chkconfig httpd on

            host_name=`curl -s
            http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname`

            echo "WELCOME TO FEBATECH WEB SERVER $host_name" >
            /var/www/html/index.html  
  ApplicationAsg:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    DependsOn:
      - PublicRouteTable
      - PublicSubnet01RouteTableAssociation
      - PublicSubnet02RouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: ApplicationAsg
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: '5'
      DesiredCapacity: '2'
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref AsgLaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt AsgLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet01
        - !Ref PublicSubnet02
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - !Ref LoadBalancer
  MyNACL:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: NACLforSSHTraffic
  InboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId:
        Ref: MyNACL
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: 6
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/24
      PortRange:
        From: 0
        To: 65535
  OutboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId:
        Ref: MyNACL
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: -1
      Egress: true
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  mySubnetNetworkAclAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet01
        - !Ref PublicSubnet02
      NetworkAclId:
        Ref: MyNACL
        
  MountTargetVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VPC
 
  MountTargetSubnetOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      VpcId: !Ref MountTargetVPC
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-south-1a"

  MountTargetSubnetTwo:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      VpcId: !Ref MountTargetVPC
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-south-1b"
  
      
 
  FileSystemResource:
    Type: 'AWS::EFS::FileSystem'
    Properties:
      BackupPolicy:
        Status: ENABLED
      PerformanceMode: maxIO
      Encrypted: true
      LifecyclePolicies:
        - TransitionToIA: AFTER_30_DAYS
      FileSystemTags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestFileSystem
      FileSystemPolicy:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"
            Principal: 'arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root'
      KmsKeyId: !GetAtt 
        - key
        - Arn
  key:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-default-1
        Statement:
          - Sid: Allow administration of the key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':root'
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
            AWS: "*"

  MountTargetResource1:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      SubnetId: !Ref MountTargetSubnetOne
      SecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt MountTargetVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup

  MountTargetResource2:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      SubnetId: !Ref MountTargetSubnetTwo
      SecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt MountTargetVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup

 
  AccessPointResource:
    Type: 'AWS::EFS::AccessPoint'
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      PosixUser:
        Uid: "13234"
        Gid: "1322"
        SecondaryGids:
          - "1344"
          - "1452"
      RootDirectory:
        CreationInfo:
          OwnerGid: "708798"
          OwnerUid: "7987987"
          Permissions: "0755"
        Path: "/mnt/abc/data"
```

The Kms key is not being created. What could most probably be done to resolve this issue. At what line could the changes be made.

Comment: Is it a duplicate question? You already got an answer on your previous question.

Comment: @Marcin No it isn't a duplicate one. Now I am getting an error while deploying the stack despite the fact that the template is valid. I have even attached a picture.

Comment: According to [the spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html), the `!GetAtt` attribute takes a single scalar. You give it a sequence at `KmsKeyId`. Maybe what you want is `!GetAtt key.Arn`?

Comment: @flyx I tried what you have said but still the problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

```sh
[cfn-lint] E3030: You must specify a valid value for CpuCredits (Unlimited).
Valid values are ["standard", "unlimited"]
[cfn-lint] E3002: Property should be of type String not List at Resources/mySubnetNetworkAclAssociation/Properties/SubnetId
[cfn-lint] E2507: IAM Policy statement key AWS isn't valid
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens probably because your `KeyPolicy` is **malformed**. There should not be `AWS: "*"` at the end:

```
  key:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-default-1
        Statement:
          - Sid: Allow administration of the key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':root'
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
            AWS: "*" #<--- This shoudn't be here
```